# ASP.NET C# FTP to GoDaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

I am adding a functionality to a website so that members can upload there own photos to their profile. The problem that I am having is my FTP capability works fine when I run it own localhost. However, after I put the site up on GoDaddy's server and try to FTP from there it does not work. I get

> Unable to connect to remote server

Here is my code:

```
protected string savePath = Path.GetTempPath();
protected string saveThumbPath = Path.GetTempPath() + "/Thumb";
Guid g;
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool worked = false;
    if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            g = Guid.NewGuid();
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
            Bitmap src = Bitmap.FromStream(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream) as Bitmap;
            Bitmap thumb = Bitmap.FromStream(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream) as Bitmap;

            // Resize the bitmap data
            //Create the large image
            Bitmap result = ProportionallyResizeBitmap(src, 800, 600);
            //string saveName = Server.MapPath(savePath) + g + filename;
            string saveName = savePath + g + filename;
            result.Save(saveName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            //Create the thumbnail
            result = ProportionallyResizeBitmap(thumb, 200, 150);
            //string saveThumbName = Server.MapPath(saveThumbPath) + g + filename;
            string saveThumbName = saveThumbPath + g + filename;
            result.Save(saveThumbName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
            worked = true;
            Thumbholder.Value = "Thumb" + g + filename;
            Photoholder.Value = g + filename;
// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
//If the specified proxy is an HTTP proxy. only the DownloadFile, ListDirectory and ListDirectoryDetails commands are supported

//get the object used to communicate with the server
System.Net.FtpWebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://mydomain/newcorvetteclub/Images/" + g + filename) as System.Net.FtpWebRequest;
//this example assumes the FTP site uses anoymous login on
//NetWorkCredentials provides credentials for  password-based authentication such as digest, basic, NTLM
request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");

//Copy the contents of the file to the request stream
byte[] fileContents = null;
if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
{
    //fileContents = FileUploadControl.FileBytes;
    fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(saveName);

}
else
{
    Response.Write("you need to provide a file");
    return;
}
request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
//GetReequestStream: retrieves the stream used to upload data to an FTP server.
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();
System.Net.FtpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.FtpWebResponse;
//Response.Write("Upload file complete, status: " + response.StatusDescription);
response.Close();
request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://mydomain/newcorvetteclub/Images/Thumb" + g + filename) as System.Net.FtpWebRequest;
request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
{
    fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(saveThumbName);
}
else
{
    Response.Write("you need to provide a file");
    return;
}
request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
//GetReequestStream: retrieves the stream used to upload data to an FTP server.
requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();
response = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.FtpWebResponse;
//Response.Write("Upload file complete, status: " + response.StatusDescription);
```

Another weird thing is that my email client is doing something similar. It works fine as long as it is being run through localhost but then times out when it it being run from GoDaddy's servers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I updated it with the image part of the code, I am not sure which line is throwing it since it works perfectly when using the debugger

Comment: @agent-j, the `Bitmap` API he's using is a shallow wrapper around GDI+.

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?  GDI+ is the windows graphics library and wouldn't have anything to do with network communications.

Comment: @Inuyasha, how can I debug when running on GoDaddy's severs?

Comment: Can you write the exception to some sort of log?

Comment: @Svisstack, I wish that I could, but I am building this site as a favor and they do not want to leave GoDaddy

Comment: @agent-j, I've been trying to figure out how to do that, but I cannot replicate the error inside my compiler environment.

Comment: try{Bitmap.FromStream(...);}catch(Exception e){File.WriteAllBytes(e.ToString(), tempFileName);}

Comment: Note that for GoDaddy, the username you use to connect to the website via the hosting interface is sometimes not the same as the user account you use for FTP - do you know what the exact error code is for your issue? Is it 530? See http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=4864 for example.

Comment: @dash, I checked and I am using the correct credentials. Can you think of anything else that might help. It works like a charm when launched from Visual Studio, but fails once it is live on GoDaddy?

Comment: @tuckerjt07 I suspect it's a trust issue. I'm pretty sure you need full trust for an outgoing ftpwebrequest but GoDaddy only allows medium trust by default. See http://mvcrecaptcha.codeplex.com/discussions/218851 and http://haacked.com/archive/2006/10/17/Why_Oh_Why_Couldnt_WebPermission_Be_Part_Of_Medium_Trust.aspx for some more info.

Comment: @tuckerjt07, add logging and exception handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you why the email isn't going through you have to use "relay-hosting.secureserver.net" as your SMTP Server. As far as the FTP is concerned you can't do it on godaddy they block outgoing ftp. I just found that out.

Comment: You were correct, the correct way to add files to godaddy is to use the .save function and save it to the filepath that they give you in your my account section.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in here, where you use the same stream for both of these calls:

```
Bitmap src = Bitmap.FromStream(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream) as Bitmap;
FileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream.Position = 0; // try this
Bitmap thumb = Bitmap.FromStream(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream) as Bitmap;
```

Streams have a current position, and so the first `.FromStream` probably reads the whole stream, setting the position of the stream to the end of stream.  To undo this, you need to reset it by setting `stream.Position = 0`.

Comment: I inserted the line that you suggested, and now I am getting an unable to connect to the remote server message. What seems odd to me is that this works when being run locally, with or without that line but does not work once taken to GoDaddy's servers

Comment: Try saving the posted file to the disk, then reading Bitmap from the disk, then deleting the file from the disk.  You may simply not have access to GDI+ from GoDaddy (I have no experience with their hosting).

Comment: that's what I am doing, I am performing all of my bitmap edits, saving that file to the local temp directory, then reading the Temp directory file back into the FtpWebRequest Stream

Comment: With respect, you are actually reading a bitmap from a stream.  A stream which is probably not written to disk.  Try writing it to the disk first, and reading into `Bitmap` second, to see if your problem is the stream or the GDI+.

Comment: please explain, I'm confused. I thought I was reading the file from the fileuploader, converting it to a bitmap stream, performing my resizing on the bitmap in that stream, saving it as a jpeg to the Temp folder, and then putting that jpeg into the ftp stream. If that is not what I am doing, it is what I intended to do and any help getting to that point would be appreciated.

Comment: You can save the stream to a file like this:
`var fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\Path\To\File");
FileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
fileStream.Close();
... new Bitmap(@"C:\Path\To\File", false)`

Comment: I have the GDI+ problem fixed, now it is saying it is unable to connect